# How can I group and sync messages in google cloud dataflow to ensure orderly processing?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, message-queue, data-processing

I'm using Google Cloud Dataflow in streamming mode to process incoming messages from cloud Pub/Sub to activate alerts based on some IoT device events (mostly related events (open/close, high/low, etc).

I need to make sure that this messages are processed in an orderly manner to ensure context is not lost.
Since some messages require more processing than others, a few end up being processed later.
The messages have associated events (for example door open, door closed) and for this reason it is necessary to respect the order of processing.

I am including an example image where messages 2 and 3 take different amounts of time to process and message 2 finishes earlier.

Could you help me find a way to achieve this with dataflow?

[image: Diagram with example]

thank you so much!

I tried to create an orchestation outside dataflow using functions and cloud sql to store and group based on a particular key but i think there must be a more simple way to achieve this with dataflow only.

EDIT: I have found this interesting article and I will try this approach (session window):
https://pavankumarkattamuri.medium.com/windowing-in-cloud-dataflow-fixed-sliding-session-becda3b12bbd